# SQL Server 2005 where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table with this columns and values:

```
Symbol        
---------------------
RELIANCE14JULFUT         
RELIANCE14JUL900CE         
RELIANCE14JUL1020CE                                
RELIANCE14JUL1040PE
RELIANCE14JUL1140PE
```

My code:

```
Declare @Date datetime;
Declare @Symbol Nvarchar (50);
Declare @SpFrom Nvarchar (50);
Declare @SpTo Nvarchar (50);

Set @Date = '07/23/2014'
Set @Symbol = 'RELIANCE14JUL'
Set @SpFrom = 1000 -------- use 1000
Set @SpTo = 1100

use GRAPHS;


Select Symbol 
from Opt
where 
    (Symbol like @Symbol+'%' and replace (Symbol, @Symbol, '') = 'FUT')
    or (left(Replace(Symbol, @Symbol, ''), len(Replace(Symbol, @Symbol, '')) - 2) between @SpFrom and @SpTo 
        and Symbol like @Symbol + '%')
```

If `@SpFrom = 1000` then I get

```
Symbol        
---------------------
RELIANCE14JULFUT                  
RELIANCE14JUL1020CE                                
RELIANCE14JUL1040PE
```

If `@SpFrom = 900` then I get only

```
Symbol        
---------------------
RELIANCE14JULFUT
```

but I need:

```
Symbol        
---------------------
RELIANCE14JULFUT         
RELIANCE14JUL900CE         
RELIANCE14JUL1020CE                                
RELIANCE14JUL1040PE
```

please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a string comparison in BETWEEN when you most likely mean to do an integer comparison. You'll need to cast your string to an integer before comparing;

```
SELECT Symbol FROM Opt
WHERE (Symbol like @Symbol+'%' AND REPLACE(Symbol,@Symbol,'')='FUT')
   OR (CAST(left(Replace(Symbol,@Symbol,''), 
            len(Replace(Symbol,@Symbol,''))-2) AS INT) 
         BETWEEN @SpFrom AND @SpTo AND Symbol LIKE @Symbol+'%')
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/66bdf/7).

Comment: it is working sir,but i have Symbols like  'NIFTY14JULFUT'  If it is there it throw a error

Comment: @gopi: well, storing multiple pieces of information into a single column like this is a **mess** - always - and it violates the first normal form of database design. IF you have multiple pieces of information (`NIFTY`, 14, `JUL`, `FUT`) - you should store those **in separate columns** - then querying would be really easy, too!

Answer (score 0):

you should to cast your number to int

try this:

```
Declare @Date datetime;
Declare @Symbol Nvarchar (50);
Declare @SpFrom INT;
Declare @SpTo INT;

Set @Date = '07/23/2014'
Set @Symbol = 'RELIANCE14JUL'
Set @SpFrom = 1000 
Set @SpTo = 1100

use GRAPHS;


Select Symbol 
from Opt
where 
    (Symbol like @Symbol+'%' and replace (Symbol, @Symbol, '') = 'FUT')
    or CAST((left(Replace(Symbol, @Symbol, ''), len(Replace(Symbol, @Symbol, '')) - 2) AS INT) between @SpFrom and @SpTo 
        and Symbol like @Symbol + '%')
```